# I'm building my first website using an API, I am a beginner in using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using OMDb API to build a movie search platform for a practise project in VS Code. I've have had trouble implementing the actual search function.

When I'm trying to set the `innerHTML` I keep getting `undefined` for my Titles for example.

```js
async function main() {

  let keyword = 'fast';

  const response = await fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=ba040381&s=${keyword}`);
  const movieData = await response.json();
  const movieListEl = document.querySelector(".movie__list");
  const movies = movieData.Search

  console.log(movieData)

  movieListEl.innerHTML = movies
    .map(
      (movies) =>
        `<div class="movie__card">
          <div class="movie__card--container">
            <h3>${movies.title}</h3>
            <p><b>Year:</b>${movies.year}</p>
            <p><b>Rating:</b>xxxxx</p>
            <p><b>Runtime:</b>xxxxx</p>
            <p><b>Genre:</b>xxxxx</p>
          </div>
        </div>`
    )
    .join("");
}

main();
```

And here is the HTML for my searchbar

```html
<div class="input__wrap">
  <input type="text" class="input__txt" placeholder="Search...">
  <div class="search__wrapper">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal here is to make the search bar functional and to actually display the movie information. Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: The issue as I can see from the image you attached(which you shouldn't do. Please read *[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70340082/how-to-add-a-screenshot-when-i-respond#:~:text=Please%20do%20not%20post%20an,.com%2F2116%2F)*.);  in `console.log` you're trying to apply the `map` function on `object`. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) needs to be applied on `arrays` and not `objects`. Because of which you're getting the error.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll be better in the future about adding screenshots correctly. This is my first tine using stack overflow in over a year. And I will look into changing my `map()` to be on the array

Comment: All good, that was the reason for the error anyways. Cheers:)That would be simple. I checked the API. It requires the `s` query to return array Do something like: `const keyword = "avengers"; // Change this keyword to search for different movies
  const response = await fetch(\`https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${keyword}&apikey=ba040381\`);
  const data = await response.json();
  const movies = data.Search;`- and then do `map` on `movies`

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. The properties on the objects in the result are capitalised. Switch `movies.title` to `movies.Title`, `movies.year` to `movies.Year`, etc

Comment: Please do not re-add the [tag:api] tag. You can clearly see in its description that it should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

The response is not array, response is only one object and you don't need to iterate, you need distructure object or accees object values directy.

```
const {Title, Year, Genre, Runtime, Ratings} = movieData
```

Or

```
movieData.Title, movieData.Genre ....
```

Then show result

```
movieListEl.innerHTML = `<div class="movie__card">
      <div class="movie__card--container">
        <h3>${Title}</h3>
        <p><b>Year:</b>000</p>
        <p><b>Rating:</b>xxxxx</p>
        <p><b>Runtime:</b>xxxxx</p>
        <p><b>Genre:</b>xxxxx</p>
      </div>
    </div>`
```

Comment: It is actually an array. I think OP's now removed screenshot showed `console.log(movies)` or similar

Answer (score -1):

You are getting error because `movieData` is an object and you cannot use `map()` method on the object in JavaScript. If `movieData` is an `Array` then you can use `map()` method to iterate over the array elements.